# Bookmarking directories

Tags: bash, shell

When working on a large codebase, I often need to switch between deeply nested directories quickly. To make my life easier, I came up with a bookmarking script.

```
#!/bin/bash

bm_list() {
    for i in "${!BOOKMARKS[@]}"; do
        echo -e $i'\t'"${BOOKMARKS[$i]}" ;
    done
}

bm_go() {
    cd "${BOOKMARKS[$1]}"
}

bm_add() {
    for i in "${!BOOKMARKS[@]}"; do
        [[ "$1" == ${BOOKMARKS[$i]} ]] && return
    done
    BOOKMARKS+=("$1")
}

bm_clear() {
    unset BOOKMARKS
}

bm_delete() {
    unset BOOKMARKS[$1]
}

bm_compact()
{
    local SIFS="$IFS"; IFS=
    BOOKMARKS=("${BOOKMARKS[@]}")
    IFS="$SIFS"
}

bm_load() {
    local bmfile=${1:-~/.bookmarks}
    local SIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'
    bm_clear
    while read -d ''; do BOOKMARKS+=("$REPLY"); done < "$bmfile"
    IFS="$SIFS"
}

bm_save() {
    local bmfile=${1:-~/.bookmarks}
    printf '%s\0' "${BOOKMARKS[@]}" > "$bmfile"
}

bm_help() {
    cat <<-EOF
bm: bookmark directories
Usage:
    bm                   bookmark current directory
    bm -l
    bm list              list bookmarks
    bm index
    bm -g index
    bm go index          cd to bookmark at index
    bm -d index
    bm delete index      delete bookmark at index
    bm -s [filename]
    bm save [filename]   save bookmarks in the file (default ~/.bookmarks)
    bm -L [filename]
    bm load [filename]   load bookmarks from the file (default !/.bookmarks)
    bm -c
    bm clear             remove all bookmarks
    bm -C
    bm compact           compact indices to a sequential list
EOF
}

bm() {
    local command=$1; shift
    case $command in
        -l | list ) bm_list ;;
        -g | go ) bm_go "$1" ;;
        -d | delete ) bm_delete "$1";;
        -s | save ) bm_save "$1" ;;
        -c | clear ) bm_clear ;;
        -C | compact ) bm_compact ;;
        -L | load ) bm_load "$1" ;;
        '') bm_add "$PWD" ;;
        *) [[ "$command" =~ [0-9]+ ]] && bm_go "$command" || bm_help ;;
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

1. [`#!/usr/bin/env bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383546/96588) is a very common shebang line these days.
2. [Use More Quotes™](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes):

   - `echo -e $i'\t'"${BOOKMARKS[$i]}"` should be `echo -e $i'\t'"${BOOKMARKS[$i]}"` (or even better, `printf '%s\t%s' "$i" "${BOOKMARKS[$i]}"`)
   - `command=$1` should be `command="$1"`
3. In `[[ "$command" =~ [0-9]+ ]]` you'll want to anchor the regex.
4. If this is for your own use I don't quite understand the need for both option-style and command-style invocation.
5. `==` in Bash is a bit of a historical accident. It won't make any difference as long as you use Bash, but I usually prefer the POSIX `=` in this case.
6. It seems `bm_compact` should run on every change, since it'll be super fast and you avoid changing indexes.
7. `bmfile` would be better as either configuration or as a single variable.
8. "default !/.bookmarks" should probably be "default ~/.bookmarks".
9. You can set `IFS` for a single command, such as `while IFS=… read …`
10. All the single semicolons are extraneous - you definitely don't need one for `echo -e $i'\t'"${BOOKMARKS[$i]}" ;`, and you can use

    ```
    for i in "${!BOOKMARKS[@]}"
    do
    ```

    for loops and conditionals.

Comment: I appreciate you elaborating on the bullet 2.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sanity check

[Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) reports a couple of issues.
I will not call them out one by one, I suggest to review and fix.

#### Incorrectly saving empty bookmark

When there are no bookmarks, `bm_save` will write a single null byte to the file.
Then, when you list bookmarks the empty entry shows up at index 0.

I suggest to add a check before actually writing to the file:

```
[[ ${#BOOKMARKS[@]} != 0 ]] || return 0
```

#### Do not raise error when file does not exist

`bm_load` raises an error if the file does not exist.
Is that the intended behavior?
I don't think so, because `bm_save` happily writes to the file.
Perhaps `bm_load` should be more forgiving.

#### Overriding `IFS`

As [@l0b0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/716/l0b0) already pointed out, it's good to prefix with `IFS=...` just the command where you want the modified value, when possible (usually).
Another alternative is to use `local IFS=...`:
the modified value will only be visible within the function,
so no need to worry about backup and restore.

#### Unnecessary overriding of `IFS`

In `bm_compact` I don't see a reason to override `IFS` to recreate `BOOKMARKS`.

Btw, at first I didn't understand the purpose of this function.
I think naming it `bm_compact_indexes` would have made it click.

#### What is `REPLY`?

I can find what is `REPLY` if I look at `help read`.
I think it will be easier to understand the code if you specify a descriptive variable name with `read`.

#### Can you use Bash 4?

Where there is Bash, there's usually Bash 4.
Using `mapfile` you could replace the loop reading `BOOKMARKS` in `bm_load` with:

```
mapfile -d '' -t BOOKMARKS < "$bmfile"
```

#### Avoid `echo -e`

The flags of `echo` don't work reliably in all systems, so I suggest to avoid it.
Your alternatives are using `printf` (which is not POSIX compliant), or (in your specific case) to embed tab characters in the string.